# Independent JUnit Tests with Springs @Autowired

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit, autowired

As a beginner in Test Driven Development I just encountered a problem. My test class begins as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/web-test.xml"})
public class XXTest {

  @Autowired
  XX xx;

  @Autowired
  HibernateTemplate template;

  @Test
  public void testSetGetXXValue() throws Exception {
    final Map<String, YY> profilMap = new HashMap<String, YY>(2);
    profilMap.put("1", new YY());
    profilMap.put("2", new YY());

    simpleCockpit.setValues(profilMap);

    assertEquals(profilMap, simpleCockpit.getValues());
  }
```

As you can see, the first test method alters the autowired XX-class. That affects all following test methods, which relies on XX having the autowired-values.

**How can I test getter and setter from XX AND make sure XX has the autowired values for the rest of the test methods?**

Thoughts:

- Reset the right values at the end of test method. Bad because if the getter / setter are not working, this will also not work.
- Place the first test method at the end of the test class. Bad because that makes the tests dependent on their execution order.
- Do not test the getter / setter of XX. Bad because getter / setter have to be tested like every method.

Thanks for you answers! I`m pretty sure this has an easy solution ... :)

**EDIT**: Regarding the questions whether unit testing getters/setters or not, I decided to do so mainly because of the reasons statet at http://www.sundog.net/sunblog/posts/should-we-test-getters-and-setters/ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you modify an spring managed bean, then you could use the `@DirtiesContext` Annotation. This Annotation can be put on Test Classes as well as on Test Methods!

From [@DirtiesContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) Java Doc:

> Test annotation which indicates that the {@link
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext ApplicationContext}
>   associated with a test is *dirty* and should be closed:
>
> - after the current test, when declared at the method level
> - after each test method in the current test class, when declared at the class
>     level with class mode set to {@link ClassMode#AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD
>     AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD}
> - after the current test class, when declared
>     at the class level with class mode set to {@link ClassMode#AFTER_CLASS
>     AFTER_CLASS}

---

And even in Test Driven Development (to my understanding): write explicite tests only for stuff that has a minimum complexity. So I never write explicite tests for getter and setter. I normally have a test that checks some functionality, and when this functionality needs the getter and setter so I write this getter and setter (at this point in time) and that they works will be checked by the functionality I started with implicit.

---

Especially in your case: why do you use the Spring Bean, why not using "normal" Objects created with `new`. I use the "normal" classes as long as it is usefull for the tests, mostly for simple tests. I use Spring Beans for "bigger" tests as well.

Comment: @DirtiesContext was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

I want to autowire this bean because it`s a DAO delivering test data from a database.